# How do I set recipients for UIActivityViewController when using message

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using this code to present UIActivityViewController.

```
 var a = standard.value(forKey: "first_name") as? String
    let text = a! + " text to share"
    let url : NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: "https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/")

    let textToShare = [ text as String , url as URL ] as [Any]
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: textToShare, applicationActivities: nil)


    activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
    activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {
        (s, ok, items, error) in
        if ok == true {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               // code after completion
            }

        }
    }
    self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But I want that, if I select the message option in UIActivityViewController then the phone number should be pre filled with the number I provide. Is this possible with UIActivityViewController or not. If yes please provide me with a some reference or code about it